# Django - Foreign Key default

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models

I have problem with setting default value for my ForeignKey field in model. Here is my code:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Slot(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,  blank = True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(SlotName)
    is_taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    usr = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event) #i would like to have something like "default=group.event" here 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name
```

This is a simple calendar app, and the idea is that i have an event that people can sign up for in specified groups. So I would like to be able to create event and at the same time create some groups, and then add slots to groups.

I have event field in Slot model because I need to make sure that people won't be able to sign up for 2 slots at the same time, and I also need to calculate number of slots (field in Event model). I obviously need event fields in both models to point to the same Event, so I thought that i could have something like a default value for my Slot.event.

Feel free to submit any workarounds, I can easily re-design my app. Thanks in advance for help.

EDIT:
I'll try to better describe my app: it's supposed to be a calendar for an online game community (the game is arma3). I expect every event to be attended by no more than 40 people, but for our gaming sessions we need hierarchy. In particular we divide ourselfes in groups, in every group there are different roles(team leader, machine gunner, rifleman etc.). I want to have a calendar in which you can view particular event details, including groups and all the different slots, and sign up for one particular slot. I hope that it clarifies it. Please forgive all errors, English is not my first language.

I forgot to mention it earlier but I am an absolute beginner at Django and am running Django 1.7 on python 3.4. The solution with using lambda does not seem to work, here is the error log (sorry for no indentations):

```
(own)qwe@qwe:~/Projects/own/src$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'cal':
0021_auto_20141202_1913.py:
- Remove field title from slot
- Alter field event on slot
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 124, in handle
self.write_migration_files(changes)
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 152, in write_migration_files
migration_string = writer.as_string()
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 129, in as_string
operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 86, in serialize
arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(arg_value)
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 310, in serialize
return cls.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 221, in serialize_deconstructed
arg_string, arg_imports = cls.serialize(arg)
File "/home/qwe/Projects/own/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 323, in serialize
raise ValueError("Cannot serialize function: lambda")
ValueError: Cannot serialize function: lambda
```

Here is updated code(again there might be indentation errors, I can't get my head around this code system here):

```
class Event(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    details = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    slots_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True)
    event_date = models.DateField(
        blank=True, null=True)
    event_time = models.TimeField(default='20:00')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    type = models.ForeignKey(EventType)


    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Slot(models.Model):
    #title = models.CharField(max_length=50,  blank = True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(SlotName)
    is_taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    usr = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name
```

Comment: What about `event = models.ForeignKey(Event, default=lambda: self.group.event  if self.group else None)` ?

Comment: ... or override `__init__`

Comment: ... Or binded to post_init signal @madzohan

Comment: I know that it might be 'noob' question but how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to add a foreign key to a migration without a default value. Remove the lambda expression and let the default value as nullable (None) and try again with the following code sample. It worked perfectly for me.

e.g:

```
from django.db import models                                                    


class Slot(models.Model):                                                       
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', null=True)                               
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', null=True)                               
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):                                            
        if(self.group is not None and self.group.event is not None):            
            self.event = self.group.event                                       
        super(Slot, self).save(*args, **kwargs)                                 

class Event(models.Model):                                                      
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)                                     

class Group(models.Model):                                                      
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)                                    
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event')
```

I omitted the non interesting fields on models for the sake of simplicity. I hope it could help you.

Comment: Well, I abandoned this concept in my app and went other way, but thanks for your answer anyway. I marked it as accepted in case anybody else encounters this problem.

Comment: You are welcome. I would appreciate if you could share the solution you got by refactoring your app. Of course, if you can share it with us.

Comment: I have no solution, I just removed Group class and linked slots to Event class. Then I added group_name charfield to Slot class, so now every Slot can have group name specified.

Answer (score 0):

Something like what daniph suggested should work:

```
event = models.ForeignKey(Event, default=lambda: self.group.event if self.group else None)
```

Now, if i understand you, events are made for specific groups and those events have slots that users can use to register for the event.

I would handle it like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Slot(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,  blank = True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(SlotName)
    is_taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    usr = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

This way makes more sense and there are no repeated foreign keys. Your slot knows what is it's event and the event knows it's owner group.

You can reverse query them like:

Slots for my event:

```
my_event.slot_set.all()
```

Events for my group:

```
my_group.event_set.all()
```

As an unrelated advice, don't user the raw user model. The right way to use it is in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

If you need to use another user model in the future, your app won't break if you do it this way.

Edit:

I misunderstood a couple things. It seems Events have several groups and groups have several slots. Now, "have several" can be represented with a foreign key.

In that case, group should have a foreign key to events, and slots should have a foreign key to groups.
You can check which is the event for a certain slot with:

```
my_slot.group.event
```

Comment: You did not understand me:) The groups are created for specific events and slots are created for specific groups. At first I had no reference from slots to groups, but as I wrote it will be helpful to easily have access to all the slots from certain event.

Comment: So, events have several groups and groups have several slots?

Comment: Exactly, I'll update the question in a minute because lambda solution did not work for me.

Comment: Check edit. Also, for that lambda to work you need to have an event and a group assigned already.

Comment: Lambda are not recommended and was removed from 1.7+ documentation. I had the same problem here withou a solution until now. Please read the documentation before suggest the solution.

Comment: By the way, the lambda solutions thows an error of serialization for migrations.

Comment: Solved the problem. I will post it as a solution here.